# Copy and pasting text between files causes leading whitespace to be trimmed in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 4, I'm having a problem with leading white space (it's being trimmed), when copy and pasting between files. In the hex dump, I see `0x20`s in the source, but not in the copy; this means the text is being changed on paste.

In `preferences > text editing > indentation`, I have `prefer indent using: spaces` and `tab key: indents in leading white space` set.

This doesn't happen on trailing whitespace. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that same Preferences > Text Editing > Indentation screen, try unchecking the **Syntax-aware indenting** option.

Answer (score 9):

You can try to use **Edit > Paste and Preserve Formatting** in Xcode. I can see it in version 5.1 but can't tell if it was there before. There is a keyboard combination for it, too: **Alt+Caps+Command+C**.

Comment: Awesome. This is the real answer.

Comment: Life saver tip.